# why do i not see the latest file in github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

first off, I'm a github newbie:

I created a new repository, imported code from another repo, cloned the repo to my disk, copied the changed files into it, called `git commit` and `git push` but if I go to my github account, open the repo, I don't see my latest commit and the files do not reflect the latest what I have on my disk either but I get the following:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
$ git commit
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   main.cpp
        modified:   mainwindow.cpp
        modified:   mainwindow.h
        modified:   session.cpp
        modified:   sessionstack.cpp
        modified:   sessionstack.h

Untracked files:
        cscope.out
        kterminal.kdev4

no changes added to commit
$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Username for 'https://github.com': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@github.com': 
Everything up-to-date
```

What am I doing wrong? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to do a `git add` before a `git commit`**

It's common to use `git add .` which will "stage" all of your changes to be committed. (i.e. mark them to be included in the next commit).

The purpose of "adding" files before committing them means that you don't have to commit all changes at once. For example, you can change ten files, stage five of them, commit them with the message "feature one", then stage the remaining 5 and commit them as "feature two"

More info: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add